consistent vertex configurations for Archimedean tiling
I am trying to find if there is a simple rule for vertex configurations $n_1.n_2\ldots n_k$ that define Archimedean tilings (equivalently called uniform/semi-regular/vertex-transitive tilings). In practical terms, an Archimedean tiling "looks the same" from the perspective of each vertex (in particular, each vertex is surrounded by the same arrangement of polygons: an $n_1$-gon, followed by an $n_2$-gon, and so on).
For example, here is an example Archimedean tiling with vertex configuration 3.4.6.4 (figure is taken from Wikipedia).

It does not matter where the resulting tiling is spherical (i.e., a polyhedron), planar, or hyperbolic (the example above is clearly planar). I am aware how to determine this aspect from the angle criterion, i.e., checking the sign of:
$$\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n_j}\right)-1.$$
The result on the consistency seems to be known: I found the Tess package for Mathematica, which first determines if a vertex configuration is consistent, and if yes then displays the tessellation. However, the package does not seem to have any documentation to explain how the consistency of the vertex configurations are checked.
An example constraint that applies to triplet configurations is discussed on Wikipedia. Namely, $n_1.n_2.n_3$ implies that an $n_1$-gon is surrounded by alternating $n_2$-gons and $n_3$-gons. Therefore, consistency requires that either $n_1$ is even or $n_2$ equals $n_3$ (and similarly for the permutations of the $n$'s). This constraint rules out the 5.5.10 configuration (which would otherwise qualify as planar).
However, it appears there are further constraints that I am not able to pin down. For example, if only one $n_j$ is odd, then it seems it has to hold that $n_{j-1}=n_{j+1}$ (which would generalize the constraint taken from the Wikipedia page). This would explain why the planar 3.4.6.4 configuration exists, while the very similar 3.4.4.6 does not.
If there are multiple odd entries, then it seems challenging to find a clear simple pattern. For example:

Configurations of the form $n_1.k^{p_1}.n_2.k^{p_2}$ seems to be consist for any two odd numbers $n_{1,2}$ and an even number $k$ when $p_{1,2}$ are of the same parity (i.e., both odd or both even), but not otherwise.
$3^k.n$ seems to be consistent whenever $k\geq 3$ and for any even/odd $n\geq 3$; however, the very similar $5^k.n$ with $k>3$ only seems to be consistent with $n=5$.

I would expect the answer to the consistency of vertex configurations to be known, but failed to find the answer by searching online. I would appreciate any suggestions for a suitable online/book reference.

Can you add an explanation of what an Archimedean tiling is? That terminology is not as familiar as you might want it to be.

@LeeMosher I added a definition, alternative names, and an illustration for the planar 3.4.6.4. I hope the question is more clear now.

The possible vertex configurations are shown at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons#Plane-vertex_tilings

@lhf Thanks. I believe the 21 arrangements listed in that table are exactly the solutions to the "angle criterion". Unfortunately, that text only lists which 11 of these arrangements give Archimedean tilings, without explaining why the other 10 don't work. Furthermore, for hyperbolic tessellations there are likely infinitely many Archimedean tilings, so listing them is not possible -- one really needs a clear rule to tell which vertex configurations are allowed/disallowed.

See also https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0097849321000078-gr2_lrg.jpg from this paper.
